# Awk printf to fix date slashes

Tags: awk

How do I remove the "/" from field $1 in this input file for an awk command? I will be printing this field as the last field. Here is my input file.

```
05/14/2021,63,131629,508138,JOSHUA KATENBRINK,85.91,CHECK,775,90131629
05/14/2021,63,107001,504026,JOHN JONES,54.62,CHECK,1354,90107001
05/14/2021,63,105071,502632,STEPHANIE WATSON,64.00,CHECK,2210,90105071
05/14/2021,63,103202,501333,CURD MARTIN INC,63.74,CHECK,5129,90103202
05/14/2021,63,103202,501332,CURD MARTIN INC,112.11,CHECK,5129,90103202
```

I tried using this but it reduces the output to "2" for field $1.

```
gsub(///,"",$1)
```

Update: I have added my awk script here for more clarity. I'm sure my liberal use of that silly "outspacer" variable is not the best choice! However, it works, so I'm trying to focus more on the slashes in the date field. And the gsub to eliminate the decimal in field $6 also fails. FYI, I am using gawk in Windows 10 using the Ubuntu Linux subsystem. Not sure if that's the reason for the escapes failing.

```
BEGIN{
FS=","
RS="\r\n"};
{
    outspacer = " ";

printf("%3s%-14s%-30s%010.2f%-16s%-9s%-20s%-92s%9s%1s%-8s%-47s\r\n",outspacer, $2, $4, gsub(".","",$6), $8, outspacer, $5,outspacer, $9,outspacer,gsub("/","",$1),outspacer);
}
```

Comment: `gsub(/\//, "", $1)` should work

Comment: `gsub("/","",$1)` seems to work, too.

Comment: "I will be printing this field as the last field" --> Can you add the complete expected output?

Comment: The gsub()s that anubhava and Wiktor suggested will work, just remember to set `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` first. Also consider changing the m/d/y order to "YYYYMMDD" in the output so you can sort on it, check for date ranges, etc.

Comment: Hi everyone. Thank you for all your responses. I loaded my awk script file for more clarity. And I also updated the original problem description. Using either version of gsub as suggested by @anubhava or Wiktor gave me the same output where that field just shows a "2" as the output.

Comment: It is because `gsub` does not return the result of the replacement, it modifies `$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
awk -F, '{outspacer = " ";a=$1;b=$6;gsub("/", "", a);gsub(/\./, "", b);printf("%3s%-14s%-30s%010d %-16s%-9s%-20s%-92s%9s%1s%-8s%-47s\r\n",outspacer, $2, $4, b, $8, outspacer, $5, outspacer, $9, outspacer, a, outspacer)}' file
```

Note that `gsub` does not return the modified string, it actually modifies the `$1` value.

Thus, to actually be able to use a modified `$1`, you can assign it to a variable, say, `a`, and then modify it with a `gsub`.

Here, `a=$1;gsub("/", "", a);` is used to set the value of Field 1 to `a` variable, then `/` are removed, and then `a` is used in the `printf` command.

With GNU `awk`, you may also use `gensub` the way you were doing:

```sh
awk -F, '{outspacer=" ";printf("%3s%-14s%-30s%010d %-16s%-9s%-20s%-92s%9s%1s%-8s%-47s\r\n",outspacer, $2, $4, gensub(/\./,"","g",$6), $8, outspacer, $5,outspacer, $9,outspacer, g
ensub("/","","g", $1),outspacer)}' file
```

Here, `gensub("/", "", "g", $1)` replaces all occurrences of a slash in Field 1 with an empty string and returns the updated value of the first field. `gensub(/\./,"","g",$6)` removes all dots in Field 6.

Comment: Thank you Wictor. It worked like a charm for the date field. I tried applying similar logic to remove the "." in my floating point value for $6. I suspect it did not work because I would need the assigned variable to be explicitly be created as a string. Is that right?

Comment: Right, overlooked it. You need `awk -F, '{outspacer=" ";printf("%3s%-14s%-30s%010.2f%-16s%-9s%-20s%-92s%9s%1s%-8s%-47s\r\n",outspacer, $2, $4, gensub(/\./,"","g",$6), $8, outspacer, $5,outspacer, $9,outspacer, g
ensub("/","","g", $1),outspacer)}' file`. I have updated both solutions.

Comment: I have a feeling my use of the "%010.2f" is throwing off the decimal point substitution. Here is my output for line 1. It seems to be still forcing the 2 decimal places when I actually don't need it.

  63            508138                        0008591.00775                      JOSHUA KATENBRINK                                                                                                90131629 05142021

Comment: I have to pad zeros to the left, the objective being to create an output file that is fixed-width and matches the start-end positions for each field. %010s will obviously not work for a string. Perhaps the best way, given I have to do a few other steps after producing the output is to just do a global search/replace of the "."! Thanks for your patience and your help.

Comment: @Jurasick Ok, then why not use `%010d`? The *printf* format string will be `"%3s%-14s%-30s%010d %-16s%-s%-20s%-92s%9s%1s%-8s%-47s\r\n"`

Comment: That's why YOU are the expert. I completely forgot there is "d" option as well! Thanks a lot. That helped clear my issue. Appreciate all your help and suggestions.